# Bucketing and one hot encoding in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe consisting of the following columns:

```
id        Age
1         30
2         25
3         21
```

I have the following age buckets: `[20, 24, 27, 30]`.

My expected result:

```
id    Age    age_bucket     age_27_30     age_24_27   age_20_24
1     30      (27-30]           1            0           0
2     25      (24-27]           0            1           0
3     21      (20-24]           0            0           1
```

My current code:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer
bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[ 20,24,27,30 ],inputCol="Age", outputCol="age_bucket")
df1 = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a result exactly as in your question, `OneHotEstimatorEncoder` will not work without some other fancy mapping tricks.

I would use a join here:

```
age_buckets = [20, 24, 27, 30]
bins = list(zip(age_buckets, age_buckets[1:]))

data = [[i] + ['({0}-{1}]'.format(*bin_endpoints)] + [0] * i + [1] + [0] * (len(bins) - i - 1) 
        for i, bin_endpoints in enumerate(bins)]
schema = ', '.join('age_bucket_{}_{}: int'.format(start, end) 
                   for start, end in zip(age_buckets, age_buckets[1:]))

join_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, 'age_bucket: int, age_bucket_string: string, ' + schema)

result = (df1.join(join_df, on='age_bucket', how='left')
             .drop('age_bucket')
             .withColumnRenamed('age_bucket_string', 'age_bucket')
             .orderBy('id'))
result.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| id|Age|age_bucket|age_bucket_20_24|age_bucket_24_27|age_bucket_27_30|
+---+---+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|  1| 30|   (27-30]|               0|               0|               1|
|  2| 25|   (24-27]|               0|               1|               0|
|  3| 21|   (20-24]|               1|               0|               0|
+---+---+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Got an error -

File "<ipython-input-89-6b1dee741fd1>", line 3
    schema = ', '.join(f'age_bucket_{start}_{end}: int'
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JohnDavis I have edited my answer to handle Python <= 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. But still facing some problems.mainly in this part - 

result = (df9.join(join_df, on='age_bucket', how='left')
             .drop('age_bucket')
             .withColumnRenamed('age_bucket_string', 'age_bucket')
             .orderBy('id'))
result.show()

AnalysisException: 'USING column `age_bucket` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [id, age];'

Comment: @JohnDavis You are performing this operation on your original `DataFrame`, `df`. You need to perform it on the output of `Bucketizer`, `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OneHotEncoderEstimator()`

```py
spark.version
'2.4.3'

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 30), (2, 25), (3, 21),],["id", "age"])

# buckets
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[20,24,27,30],inputCol="age", outputCol="age_bucket", handleInvalid="keep")
buckets = bucketizer.transform(df)

buckets.show()
+---+---+----------+
| id|age|age_bucket|
+---+---+----------+
|  1| 30|       2.0|
|  2| 25|       1.0|
|  3| 21|       0.0|
+---+---+----------+

# ohe
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator

encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=["age_bucket"], outputCols=["age_ohe"])

model = encoder.fit(buckets)
transform_model = model.transform(buckets)

transform_model.show()
+---+---+----------+-------------+
| id|age|age_bucket|      age_ohe|
+---+---+----------+-------------+
|  1| 30|       2.0|    (2,[],[])|
|  2| 25|       1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  3| 21|       0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
+---+---+----------+-------------+

# wrap it up in a pipeline if you want
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[20,24,27,30], inputCol="age", outputCol="age_bucket")
encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=["age_bucket"], outputCols=["age_ohe"])

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[bucketizer, encoder])

model = pipeline.fit(df)
fe = model.transform(df)

fe.show()
+---+---+----------+-------------+
| id|age|age_bucket|      age_ohe|
+---+---+----------+-------------+
|  1| 30|       2.0|    (2,[],[])|
|  2| 25|       1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
|  3| 21|       0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
+---+---+----------+-------------+
```